# GXT3 ComboBox multiselect

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

How in GXT 3 or GWT 2.5 we can create multiselect for comboboxes? `ListView` does not support this functionallity?

I'm playing with `ComboBoxCell` and `CheckBoxCell`, how merge their functionallity in `ListView` class? 
Also i'm trying to use `@XTemplate` annotation for creating checkboxes based on HTML. But i think this is a bad practice

Comment: May this helps you http://bhat86.blogspot.in/2012/02/gxt-comobobox-with-multi-select-feature.html

Comment: Its for GXT2, i'm working with GXT3

Comment: @Helicopter Idea is same. I have used the same idea to implement it in GXT 3. Extend the comboBox, use custom Expand and collapse handler, and show a Window, that contains a grid. On collapsing, read the checked column, and set the value of comboBox to comma separated strings. Try this, If you are getting trouble, then i will post the code

Comment: A fake CheckBoxListView using a Tree with only root nodes  tree.setCheckable(true);

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I implemented something for a toolbar.

[MultiSelectButton](https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/gwt/src/main/java/biz/freshcode/learn/gwt2/mod2/client/spike/multiselectbutton/reuse/MultiSelectButton.java) is a TextButton with a menu full of check boxes and a summary is placed in the button label (EG: "Selected: 4/6").